# Не отрабатывает скрипт FancyBox плавные переходы в галерее

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, fancybox

Подключил в шаблон Wordpress скрипт FancyBox 2. Настроил галерею, но почему-то не настраиваются переходы.
Собственно скрипт настройки:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery(".fancybox").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({
        openEffect : 'fade',
        closeEffect: 'fade',
        nextEffect : 'fade',
        prevEffect : 'fade',
        padding    : 0,
        helpers    : {
           overlay  : {
              css    : {
                'background' : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95)'
                }
                      }
           },
        closeClick : false,
        closeBtn   : false,
    });
});
```

Подключено все правильно, но при работе скрипта не происходит плавный переход фотографий в галерее. Каждая последующая вылетает из верхнего левого угла, что раздражает и не получается исправить.

Может быть Fancybox конфликтует с каким-нибудь скриптом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему помог выявить верстальщик. В стилях был вот такой код: `.load *{ -webkit-transition:all 1s; transition:all 1s;}` который блокировал нормальную анимацию. Добавил в стили `.fancybox-wrap{transition:none;}` и все переходы заработали.